# Enable a textarea only if a radio button is selected

Tags: jquery, radio-button, textarea

I have a feedback system in this website I'm building and users are asked to provide feedback for the service they've received. They have a choice to either provide an actual feedback or skip the entire thing. I have 2 radio buttons (1 for positive; the other negative)

```
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" id="green" /><label for="green">Positive</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="0" id="red" /><label for="red">Negative</label>
```

Then, I have a `textarea` for users to provide the actual feedback.

```
<textarea style="width: 95%;" rows="6" name="feedback"></textarea>
```

I'd rather have the textarea enabled **ONLY** if the user clicks on an actual radio button. If not, the textarea remains disabled. How should I go about this? (I'm thinking jQuery)

Thanks, guys.

[EDIT]

Thanks for the quick input, guys. Also, if I may add, what if let's say I'm generating the rows from data in MySQL. Which makes the names (ie. for userid 1) name=rating[1] and name=feedback[1]. How do I select them using jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('input[name="rating"]').on('change', function() {
    $('textarea[name="feedback"]').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/933DJ/

---

Update according to your comment:

```
$('input[name="rating"]').on('change', function() {
    $('textarea[name="feedback"]').attr('disabled', false).focus();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/933DJ/1/

Comment: Thanks, though I want the text area to be displayed and not hidden.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please check on this: http://jsfiddle.net/hqfBt/ I want jQuery to just enable the textarea that corresponds to the radio buttons, not all textareas.

Comment: Thanks for the trouble. 'preciate it, buddy.

Answer (score 3):

You should set the textarea like this

```
<textarea style="width: 95%;" rows="6" name="feedback" disabled></textarea>
```

and then

```
$('input[name=rating]').click(function(){
   $('textarea[name=feedback]').removeProp('disabled');
})
```

Comment: Just a note to the OP to say removeProp is only for 1.6 and onwards, attr would work for prior to 1.6

Comment: Thanks, and what if let's say I'm generating the rows from data in MySQL. Which makes the names (ie. for userid 1) name=rating[1] and name=feedback[1]. My bad, I forgot to include this in the question.

Comment: @MikeSanchez then you have to escape the special characters like this `$('input[name=rating\\[1\\]]')`

Comment: @Nicola That works for userid 1. How about userid 2, 3, 4, etc. I'm estimating around a hundred users.

Comment: @MikeSanchez use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/): `$('input[name^=rating]')`

Comment: @MikeSanchez do it like this (i'v added the table tag otherwise the html was invalis) http://jsfiddle.net/hqfBt/4/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery 1.7+, you can do:

```
$("input[name=rating]").click(function(){
    $("#textareaid").prop("disabled", this.checked);
});
```

(Note use of prop vs attr)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="f1" action="" >
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" id="green" onclick="somefunction(0)"/><label for="green">Positive</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="0" id="red" onclick="somefunction(1)" /><label for="red">Negative</label>
<textarea style="width: 95%;" rows="6" name="feedback" readonly="readonly" ></textarea>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

function somefunction(val)
{
    if(val)
document.f1.feedback.setAttribute("readonly",val)
else
document.f1.feedback.removeAttribute("readonly",val)


}
</script>
```