# I need help connecting my textbox to my radio button?

Tags: html, textbox, radio-button

In the web page that I am working on I have to setup a page that allows the user to choose two files and compare them. They are given three choices. One of these choices uses a text box for user input. When I try implementing this I found that the text box was not connected to the intended option. It could be accessed from the other options. I would like help fixing my text box so that it is exclusively connected to the third object "substrings".

```html
<form action="/compare" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

    <button> Choose File 1</button><br>
    <button>Choose File 2</button><br>
    <input type="radio" name="compare" value="lines"> lines<br>
    <input type="radio" name="compare" value="sentences"> sentences<br>
    <input type="radio" name="compare" value="substrings"> substrings
    <input type="number" min="1" placeholder="length of substring n"/><br>

    <button type="submit">Compare</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are comparing those files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable a textarea only if a radio button is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410191/enable-a-textarea-only-if-a-radio-button-is-selected)